# JPA foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: java, database, jpa

We have a table in the database which has the following structure:

```
referenceId - int foreign key to various tables
tableReference - String defining the table
```

Is this good design, and is it somehow possible to map this relation?

Comment: Clear JPA does not provide such functionality. You have to look at JPA Providers add-on's.

Answer (score 6):

This is **very few** information to advise you any solution, but [JPA Joined Inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) works something like that:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PROJ_TYPE")
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public abstract class Project {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("L")
@Table(name="LARGEPROJECT")
public class LargeProject extends Project {
  private BigDecimal budget;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
@Table(name="SMALLPROJECT")
  public class SmallProject extends Project {
}
```

This will manage three tables in DB where the main table `PROJECT` which contain a column `PROJ_TYPE` to identify the target table.